# MapInfo Calculating the number of Points that Fall within a Boundary

Tags: sql, mapinfo, select-by-location

I have two layers in MapInfo (points and polygons). I need to select points which fall within polygons where the income > 1500

I tryed this one but not working: http://www.sgsi.com/MIUserGroup/imgs/sql1.jpg

I also tryed this SQL code but doesn't work:
points.Obj Within polygon.Obj where income > 1500

Any idea?

Comment: You seem to be going about this the right way, which suggests that there is something missing in the files your working with. Can you check the Polygon file to make sure that has income data in it? The first step of the query is a selection of those polygons meeting the >1500 criteria - so that is critical for the query. If the Polygon file contains income data, check the formatting of it - you're using a numerical value, so make sure the data is in that format. ALWAYS (!) break the problem down into a logical order.

Answer (score 3):

The where condition you are looking for is:

```
points.Obj Within polygon.Obj AND polygon.income > 1500
```

You can also solve the problem by using a sub select query instead of a join query. Here is how to fill in the details in the SQL Select dialog:

Select: *

From:    POINTS

Where: OBJ Within Any (Select OBJ From POLYGON Where INCOME > 1500)

Or in a Select expression it would look like this:

```
Select *
From POINTS
Where OBJ Within Any (Select OBJ From POLYGON Where INCOME > 1500)
```

Comment: Thank u! It works fine :) But when i export to kml the selected and saved query tab, it has no attribute data. How can i export kml or shp with attribute data?

Comment: This is not an answer and so I will convert it to a comment on the answer to which I think it relates.  You make no mention of KML in your original question so if you have a new one please post it instead of changing the scope of your question after it has been answered.  The [Tour] should make our protocols a little clearer.

Comment: Just a note that subselects in MapInfo are horrendously slow, so stick with the first solution.

Comment: Very Much appreciated. It helps a lot.Thanks Peter